# Which USB C cable has DN1, DN2, DP1 and DP2 or which USB C cable has A6, A7, B6 and B7 connected in both cable and receptacle?

Tags: usb, usb-c, thunderbolt

I have designed a custom PCB to take sensor data over USB C. I need to use both differential pairs to send data over cause my sensor has 10 pins. I would like to know which USB C cable has all the 24 pins in USB C receptacle? Or should I make a custom USB C cable?

Answer (score 2):

No official USB Type-C cable has those pins as the standard says that in cable only A6 and A7 are wired and thus B6 and B7 are disconnected.

So if you manage to find a cable that also wires B6 and B7, that is not a standard compliant USB cable so it can't be called an USB cable and should not exist.

It would get mixed up with standard cables and work poorly as a standard USB cable due to the incorrect wiring.

I suggest not to use connectors used for some standard to other non-standard purposes, as they are rarely a good idea, and makes things incompatible.

Someone will try to replace the cable with a standard longer or shorter one, and it would not work if it's not your custom cable.

And someone will try to plug your device into a standard USB device since it has a standard receptacle and plug. Connecting it to PC or phohe or charger or whatever may damage your sensors or the phone.

Make your life easier, don't use non-standard cables with standard connectors. Use something else.